# Redirect Primary Domain to https but all Sub-domains to http with mod_rewrite and htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https, wildcard-subdomain

**The Details**

I have a business host gator account..not bragging.. that comes with a free Private SSL and IP. I am running a wordpress MU install that uses the sub-domain setting and have domain mapping setup via a plugin they offer.

Assuming you know nothing about Worpress MU... basically the Wordpress MU allows you to create multiple self hosted blogs under a single Wordpress install. I have a wildcard sub-domain setup to catch all sub.domain.com requests and Wordpress MU does some voodoo to redirect it to the proper destination.

The private SSL is FREE so I am not going to shell out for a wildcard SSL right now but I do know that is an option. With that said when I, when I click any link from the https on the primary domain to a sub-domain the https sticks to the URL.

**Can anyone help me do the following?**

(please note: I had to add space between http(s):// and www below to break links in order to post my question)

For the primary "blog" url I would like both example www.domain.com and domain.com to redirect to a secure https with the result being https:// www.domain.com

For the "wildcard" sub-domain "sub-blog" url I would like example sub.domain.com and https:// sub.domain.com to redirect away form ssl to http with the result being http:// sub.domain.com

Code example would be appreciated and *a detailed (dummy) tutorial so I can understand what is going on would be great*. I am new to mod_rewrite my skill level is limited to basic 301 redirect.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use that in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 

# redirect to https www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# redirect to http subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is great and the way you created two separate rules really helped put things in perspective for me of how things work. I think I have a direction now.

works great for redirecting links that do not have https: but will not redirect https to http.

I will read a few tutorials so I have a better grasp of the language and see if I can get that working. I will post up my solution.

Comment: The second RewriteRule redirect subdomain to http. You just have to change `domain` with your real domain name...

Comment: Thank you Croises. I understand how to use the code and it works well but only solves 75% of the issue. it will redirect a url with http to use https..it will redirect www. to https and sub. to http...it will not redirect https to http. anything I have tried so far throws me into a loop.

Comment: I redirect https subdomain to http. Give me an example of a link which does not work (with the desired result)

Comment: I think you made a mistake when you corrected my example. You just have to change 2x `domain` nothing else (with a .com domain)

Comment: RewriteEngine on 

# redirect to https www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(nwamix\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# redirect to http subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+\.nwamix\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: Work well from here. Clear your cache or test from other browser. But you can't avoid de first certificat request before the redirect.